# Laplace transform of Brownian motion functional

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, laplace-transform

Let $(B_r,r\geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$ started at $0$. I am interested in the quantity
$$g(s,t) = \mathbb{E}_0\left[ \exp \left(- \beta \int_s^t \left\vert \frac{B_r}{r}\right\vert^2 dr \right)\right], $$
for $0<s \leq t$. I'm especially interested in the behaviour as $t\to \infty$. One can check that $g(s,t)=g(1/t,1/s)$ for all $s,t$ which leads me to believe that the leading order should be polynomial in $\frac{t}{s}$.

Any help would be appreciated! I tried checking the handbook of Brownian motion and some other texts but have found nothing yet.

Comment: I am guessing from the norm symbol in the integrand that your "standard" Brownian motion is not in the line. If that is correct, where is it taking place?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that it’s meant to be on $\mathbb{R}$. We did the analysis for exponents less than $2$. There we used a Feynman-Kac + PDE approach but it doesn’t work if you have $2$ as exponent. And having $2$ as exponent seems more natural so I wondered if I could find the computation somewhere.

Comment: In "Laplace Transforms via Hadamard Factorization" they study this quantity for general Gaussian processes https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~fuchang/res/EJP.pdf.

Comment: In https://www.jstor.org/stable/2692009?seq=1 "On the Distribution of the Square Integral of the Brownian Bridge", they discuss that the law for integrated square BM is known (even the density). I would guess that the methods can be modified for the case of dividing by 1/r^2.

Comment: Thank you for the references @ThomasKojar! Especially the first one with the Hadamard Factorisation looks promising, I tried their approach and it almost went through. (My basic ODE solving skills are being challenged...) I will update once I have cleaned up the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the reference of @Thomas Kojar, I now have a solution. The method using the Hadamard factorisation in [https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~fuchang/res/EJP.pdf](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/%7Efuchang/res/EJP.pdf) (Gao, Hannig, Lee, Torcaso; EJP 2003) works.

A quick summary of the method: Let's focus on $g(1,t)$ because $g(s,t)=g(1,t/s)$. Think of $(B_s/s, s \in [1,t])$ as Gaussian process.
The only thing that matters for the Laplace transform are the eigenvalues of the covariance operator $Kf(s)= \int_1^t k(r,s) f(r) dr $ where
$$k(r,s) = Cov(B_r/r, B_s/s) = \frac{r \wedge s}{rs}.$$
Note that we can translate the eigenvalue problem $Kf = \lambda f$ to an ODE
$$s^2f''(s) + 2sf'(s)+\frac{1}{\lambda}f(s) = 0,$$
for all $s\in (1,t)$ with boundary conditions $f'(1)=0$ and $f'(t) = -f(t)/2$.

Now the paper tells you that you should find a function $\varphi$ such that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\varphi(1/\lambda) =0$ and such that $\varphi(\varrho)$ is an entire function in the sense of complex analysis of order $<1$. If this exists, then
$$g(1,t) = \left(\frac{\varphi(-2\beta)}{\varphi(0)}\right)^{-1/2}.$$
This indeed works and you get an explicit expression for $g$. Asymptotically, as $t\to \infty$, this expression reduces to
$$g(1,t) \sim \left(8 \frac{\sqrt{1+8\beta }}{\sqrt{1+8\beta } + 1 } \right) ^{1/2} t^{-\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{1+8\beta } -1) }. $$

*Remark: This is a fun method and would basically work for the $L^2$-norm of any Gaussian process, as well as for similar things.*